# find missing dates from a folder using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop

I have a requirement to find the list of missing dates from a folder structure. For every date a folder is created. The folder structure is like below

```
a/b/c/20211018
a/b/c/20211019
a/b/c/20211020
```

I have written a shell script to achieve this which is working fine, but it's taking too long (7 minutes to process 150 files). Can you suggest any change to the script to make it run faster?

Below is the code snippet

```
date
startdate=20210524
enddate=20211022
root_dir="a/b/c"
d=0
n=0
until [ "$d" = "$enddate" ]
do  
    ((n++))
    d=$(date -d "$startdate + $n days" +%Y%m%d)
    hdfs dfs -test -d $root_dir/$d
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
        echo "File does not exist for $d"
    fi
done
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The slowdown will be the time it takes to do each HDFS call. You'd be better off running a single HDFS call that pulls back the names of all files in the given root directory and then iterating over that local list.

Comment: I can't test this, but I like Ben Watson's idea above -- using something like `hadoop fs -stat "%n" URI1 URI2 URI3 ... every URI` and then parsing it locally for the missing ones.

Comment: Can you just use `[[ -d "$root_dir/$d" ]]`?

Comment: Thanks for your response.@BenWatson was right.HDFS call was taking time.I modified it and it's running finr now.